# Multiple ajax request (Singleton Pattern)

Tags: django, double-click

I am using django restless for an ajax POST request, which took almost 10 to 20 seconds.

Here is my code.

```
class testEndPoint(Endpoint):
    def post(self, request):
        testForm = TestEmailForm(request.data)
        if testForm.is_valid():
            sometable = EmailTable.object.get(**condition)
            if sometable.is_email_sent == false:
                #Send Email
                #Took around 15 seconds
                sometable.is_email_sent = true
                sometable.save()
        else:
            result = testForm.errors
        return serialize(result)
```

i am calling it via `$.ajax`, but the problem is if two request hit this url with milliseconds time difference, both request passed through `if sometable.is_email_sent = false:` condition.

How can i prevent multiple submission. Right now i have moved `sometable.is_email_sent = true;sometable.save();` before email send part, but i need more generic solution as there are dozen more places where this is happening. I am on django 1.5

[django restless](https://django-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Not into django and just passing through but cant you just set your $.ajax to async false?

Comment: i need server side solution..

Comment: Synchronous ajax is almost never what you want (you could end up freezing the entire browser for 15 seconds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should disable the originating input element before you start your ajax call (that will prevent the majority of these issues).

The remaining problems can be solved by using select_for_update

```
class testEndPoint(Endpoint):
    @transaction.commit_manually
    def post(self, request):
        testForm = TestEmailForm(request.data)
        if testForm.is_valid():
            condition['is_email_sent'] = False
            try:
                rows = EmailTable.objects.select_for_update().filter(**condition)
                for row in rows:
                    row.is_email_sent = True
                    row.save()
                    #Send Email
            except:
                transaction.rollback()
                raise
            else:
                transaction.commit()

        else:
            result = testForm.errors
        return serialize(result)
```

`select_for_update` will lock the rows until the end of the transaction (i.e. it needs to be inside a transaction). By adding `is_email_sent=False` to the `condition`, we can remove the if. I've moved the changing of `is_email_sent` above the "Send Email", but it is not strictly necessary -- in any case it will be undone by the transaction rolling back if there is an exception.

Comment: thats great, i am on django 1.5, and there is no transaction.atomic

Comment: i have't tested your code, but can you again look on the condition part. I have two problems here, one with same user doing multiple request and the other is multiple users doing same request on the same time.

Comment: Both should be taken care of by the `select_for_update` it literally (literally!) locks the records in the database until it receives a `transaction.commit()`.  The only problem is that there might be some wait time for users hitting the lock. Transactions are your friends :-)